# Is there any way to find similar files (not duplicates)?

Tags: find, comparison, diff

My final goal is refactoring code written by my coworkers. So, is there a tool which can find files differing in only few words?

(Edit: this is for a Mac, but others might like non-Mac answers too.)

Comment: @harry, given [the revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/154699/revisions), I guess you posted a Windows answer, which was downvoted because only then the Mac requirement emerged? I'd rather have the Mac requirement dropped and see your answer (if it was a good non-Mac answer) as well!

Comment: @Arjan : Done .

Comment: For a Mac, I wondered if Spotlight could be used. I doubt it, but if you know of a way to do things in Spotlight, then the `mdfind` command might help to write some script to automate things. However, I think it will always only use meta data. Hence finding similar files might limit on file type, but not on file contents. No cigar.

Answer (score 6):

[Simian](https://web.archive.org/web/20100425051413/http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) does this for the source code of some languages. It is best at finding blatant copy-n-paste coding. Its developments seems to have stalled, but it works good enough.

Comment: Did not help very much — in rails app with a lot of very similar partials it only said, that I have similar lines in development.log

Comment: Did you give it the right files to analyze? You probably care about your sources, not `development.log`. For rails have a look at flay http://rubyforge.org/frs/shownotes.php?group_id=1513&release_id=38004

Comment: Yes I gave it all files in rails app dir

Comment: The link to Simian is now broken.

Comment: New link here: https://simian.quandarypeak.com/, although I'm not sure if it's the same tool.

Answer (score 4):

(For Windows)

The product [Anti-Twin](http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/) (free for private use) [claims](http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/similar.html) to be able to do this:

> If you want Anti-Twin not only to
>   search for full duplicates but also to
>   similar files, you can reduce the
>   desired minimum match from the default
>   value of 100% to up to 60%. This
>   function has been particularly
>   designed for the search of almost
>   identical files where only a tiny
>   detail was changed. Anti-Twin uses the
>   similarity search as soon as you enter
>   a value below 100%. The similarity
>   comparison takes much longer than the
>   100% full duplicate search!
>
> Unfortunately, the similarity search
>   as part of the byte-by-byte comparison
>   only makes sense for a few file types,
>   because a similarity can only be
>   detected if the files are uncompressed
>   and unencrypted. Uncompressed files
>   are e.g. unformatted texts (.TXT) and
>   HTML.

Comment: I'm on mac and running something through wine, parallels or something like that will not make refactoring easier, only harder :)

Comment: @tig: You should have specified this in your post. I've added the mac tag.

Comment: @Arjan: I undeleted this answer, as you requested.

Comment: rightfully so! Removed the `[mac]` tag again. Should have been `[osx]` anyway ;-)

Comment: The 60% similarity-limit limits its utility somewhat.